# # edges = # of vertices implies unique simple cycle

Tags: graph-theory

I received a review of one of my papers in which the reviewer made an objection:

"...from the equations e(G) = v(G) you derive that there is a unique simple cycle of G. This is false for non-simple graphs (with loops)."

Here e(G) and v(G) are the number of edges and vertices of the graph, respectively. G is assumed to be connected.

I think the definition of a simple cycle is a path that begins and ends at the same vertex and does not repeat any vertices or edges (and uniqueness is up to cyclic permutation, i.e., the starting point doesn't matter).

I can't think of any counterexample even when I allow multiple edges between vertices, or loops (an edge from a vertex to itself). In fact, I feel like this should be easy to prove. Am I missing something?

Comment: A loop is a simple cycle: it repeats no edge, and the only repeated vertex is the one at which it begins and ends.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I think "loops" here has the sense of a self-edge, which is why the number of edges and vertices can be decoupled from existence of "a unique simple cycle".

Comment: I second @hardmath's comment - a simple graph cannot have an edge from a vertex to itself, nor multiple edges between a single pair of vertices.  But a non-simple graph could consist of two vertices, $a$ and $b$, and edges from $a$ to $a$, and from $b$ to $b$. Here $e(G) = v(G)$ but there is not a unique simple cycle in $G$.

Comment: @Titus "$G$ is assumed to be connected."

Comment: @Titus: Your example illustrates the reviewer’s point. I don’t see the point of **hardmath**’s comment, since we’re apparently talking about exactly the same thing: an edge from a vertex $v$ to $v$.

Comment: @bof Good catch.  Then yeah, if you have $e(G) = v(G)$ I think you must have a unique cycle.  With $n$ vertices you'll have to use $n-1$ edges to connect all vertices to one another (forming a spanning tree).  Now you have to add an edge to a connected graph without forming a loop.  Not going to happen.

Comment: A graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges is a tree plus one more edge. Adding an edge to a tree will always result in a graph with exactly one (simple) cycle; it doesn't matter if the extra edge duplicates an existing edge (making a $2$-cycle) or joins a vertex to itself (making a $1$-cycle), it's still a unique cycle.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I apologize for my misunderstanding of your initial Comment, mistaking "a loop is a simple cycle" for the definition of simple cycle that you then gave (rather than "a loop is an instance of a simple cycle" as you doubtless mean).

Comment: @hardmath: No problem. And yes, I did mean that a loop is an instance of a simple cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we cannot have a simple graph where $e (G)=v (G) $ is one or two.  However it is possible to have non-simple graphs which are connected and satisfy $e (G)=v (G) $ without being simple cycles.

Consider a tree with four vertices and three edges.  Now add one more edge that either duplicates an existing edge or puts a loop (self-edge) on a leaf vertex.

The result remains connected but is no longer a simple graph, and in particular is neither a simple cycle nor contains a simple cycle except a loop or double-edge between two vertices.

---

If these are allowed (and the OP has not spoken up to say not so), then we can prove the uniqueness of the simple cycle contained in the connected (undirected) graph $G$.

If $G$ did not contain a cycle, even of the loop or double-edge variety, yet was connected, then it would be tree and $e(G)$ would be $v(G)-1$ (a proof of this by induction is easy and has been discussed previously at Math.SE).  On the other hand if $G$ were a connected simple graph with $e(G)=v(G)$, then $G$ itself would be a single cycle of length $e(G)=v(G)$.

Finally if $G$ is connected with $e(G)=v(G)$, then it differs from a spanning tree $T$ contained in $G$ by a single edge.  So if $G$ is not itself a cycle, then the extra edge in $G$ but not in $T$ must be a loop (self-edge) or a duplicate (parallel) of an edge in $T$.  As any cycle in $G$ must use the edge which doesn't belong to $T$, we see in either of those cases that the "simple cycle" of $G$ is unique, a loop or a pair of parallel edges.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) defines a *simple cycle* as "a closed walk with no repetitions of vertices and edges allowed, other than the repetition of the starting and ending vertex."  By that definition, a graph containing one vertex $v$ and one edge joining $v$ to $v$ is a simple cycle, and so is a graph containing two vertices $u,v$ and two edges joining $u$ to $v$. Of course neither of those simple cycles is a simple graph.

Comment: The use of terms *cycle* and *simple cycle* vary with authors.  I've edited my last statement to exclude the cases noted in my opening paragraph.

Comment: I expect that this was this confusion: the reviewer was assuming that a loop or multi-edge is not a cycle (i.e. a cycle has length at least 3), but I was assuming that they are. I'll be sure to clarify this in my paper. I'll accept this answer.